# Copy a template worksheet multiple times in a new workbook with different worksheet names

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to complete a VBA routine for the first time.

The goal is :

Use a vertical range of cell that have different names in each cell to create multiples worksheets in one new workbook.

Here's what i got until now :

```
Sub AddWorksheet()

Dim plage As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim titre As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Set plage = Range("E6:E24")

Set wb = Workbooks.Add("New Workbook")

For i = 1 To plage.Height

If plage.Cells(i).Value <> "" Then
titre = plage.Cells(i).Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FeuilleTemplate").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = titre

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Until now the following line is giving me a hard time :

```
Set wb = Workbooks.add("New Worbook")
```

The error message is : Error execution '1004' : 
The method 'dd' of the object 'Workbooks' has failed.

I'm having a hard time reading and finding the info too for how the methods and class works

I'm use to java.

Thanx for those who gona take time to help me thru this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we cannot add a workbook with a specified name as it is not yet saved. So just add workbook do all the operations and in the end save it with the desired name.

```
Sub AddWorksheet()
Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Dim plage As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim OldBook As Workbook, NewBook As Workbook 'declare both workbooks
Set OldBook = ActiveWorkbook
spath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Set plage = OldBook.Sheets("Sheet Names").Range("E6:E24") 'Assuming that sheet names are in range E6:E24 in "Sheet Names" sheet in old workbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add 'adding new workbook so as to copy the template sheet but this workbook is not saved yet
For i = 1 To plage.Height
    If plage.Cells(i).Value <> "" Then 'for each non blank cell in range
        OldBook.Sheets("FeuilleTemplate").Copy After:=NewBook.Sheets(NewBook.Sheets.Count) 'Copy "FeuilleTemplate" sheet in workbook after last sheet
        NewBook.Sheets("FeuilleTemplate").Name = plage.Cells(i).Value 'Rename the sheet to the desired names from range E6:E24 in "Sheet Names" sheet in old workbook
    End If
Next i
With NewBook
    .SaveAs Filename:=spath & "\" & "New Workbook with Templates"
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What if i want to modify the text in the cell A1 with the name of the sheet ? 

Doesnt seem to work properly : 

NewBook.Sheets(plage.Cells(i).Value).Cells(1, 1).Value = plage.Cells(i).Value

Comment: Finally this worked perfectly :

NewBook.Worksheets(plage.Cells(i).Value).Range("A1").Value = plage.Cells(i).Value